# How can I install ubuntu gnome in german

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, language-support

I installed ubuntu gnome, german is selected in the language and keyboard but all the application icons on the overview page are in english.

This has happened several times whilst installing. How can I get the application names to show in german on the overview?

Comment: What do you mean by the overview?

Comment: The activities overview where you see the dash. If you start searching for applications, all the application names and descriptions appear in english even though the OS is setup and was installed in german

Comment: Ah.  Yes not all applications get translated in all languages.  Application names usually don't change because it's a proper name, but descriptions should have a translation.  As noted in the answer below, all you can do is file a bug report unfortunately.  Or, translate them manually yourself if this is something you're doing on a large scale with a set group of applications.

Answer (score 3):

When I looked, I saw a mix of German and English. One item which is not translated is "Firefox Web Browser", and the explanation can be found in this file:

```
$ head /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Name[ar]=متصفح الويب فَيَرفُكْس
Name[ast]=Restolador web Firefox
Name[bn]=ফায়ারফক্স ওয়েব ব্রাউজার
Name[ca]=Navegador web Firefox
Name[cs]=Firefox Webový prohlížeč
Name[da]=Firefox - internetbrowser
Name[el]=Περιηγητής Firefox
```

As you can see, there is no "Name[de]" item, i.e. the German translators have not translated the original name.

So what you can do is picking *specific* missing translations, rather than referring to "the overview", and file [bug reports to the Ubuntu translations project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations).